# How can I move a sub-folder to another main folder within same s3 bucket boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

```py
dst= s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket_name', )   

copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'bucket_name',
    'Key': 'folder_path'
}   

dst.copy(copy_source,'Key': 'target_folder_path')
```

Comment: There are no such things as folders in S3, just objects with keys and some keys may have overlapping prefixes. Do you want to move all files under a given prefix to a different prefix? S3 generally does not have a "move", you always need a "copy" and then "delete".

Comment: @luk2302 yes i want to move all files but within the same bucket. Can you help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to:

- Loop through a list of the objects to 'move' (you can specify a prefix with `s3_resource.Bucket('bucket-name').objects.filter(Prefix='path/')`)
- For each object you wish to 'move':
- Use `copy()` to copy the object to the desired path
- Then `delete()` the source object

Comment: im using it at low level that is client

Comment: Same goes for using an S3 client. You can use `list_objects_v2()` to get the list of objects, then use `copy_object()` and `delete_object()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help John Rotenstein. I have been able to work it out as you explained